# How do you get image from this kind off links using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to receive and use an api from another site using php. How would I get the link?

https://assetgame.roblox.com/Asset/?id=942531508

this links downloads a file auto, but how would I save it using php (to a path on my site)?

And changing the file extention to .PNG?

Comment: What have you tried? Got any code examples of your efforts thus far and what problems you have run into?

Comment: I’ve tried to save the file on my server using methods such as curl

Comment: Have you done anything programmatically?  Have you searched, and are other solutions not working for you?

Comment: I have searched and tried many methods, which didnt work

Comment: Show us the "many methods" you have tried and update your question with the code that "didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents("gh", "https://assetgame.roblox.com/Asset/?id=942531508");
```

you want to brother with gd library for converting if this is not a png